# how to make this code snippet an arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm building a currency converter app.
How can I make this code into an arrow function `populateCurrencies`?

```
currencies.forEach(function populateCurrencies (currency) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = currency.id;
    option.innerHTML = currency.name;
    selector.appendChild(option)
});
```

Comment: do you mean like `currency => {...}`

Comment: It's unclear from your question whether you want the forEach to be part of the arrow function or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
populateCurrencies = () => {
    return currencies.forEach(function populateCurrencies (currency) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = currency.id;
        option.innerHTML = currency.name;
        selector.appendChild(option)
    });
```

Comment: I wouldn't name the inner function.  I'd leave it anonymous; or make it an arrow function too.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it inline like so:

```
currencies.forEach(currency => {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = currency.id;
    option.innerHTML = currency.name;
    selector.appendChild(option);
});
```

Since you only have one argument, you can omit the parentheses around the argument. If you had two arguments, you would need parens, for example `(currency, someOtherArg) => {...`

Comment: Please add an explanation of what was wrong and why. Your answer came up in the Low Quality Posts queue.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

```js
var currencies = [{
  id: 0,
  name: "euro"
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: "usd"
}];
var selector = document.querySelector("#selector");


currencies.forEach(currency => {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = currency.id;
  option.innerHTML = currency.name;
  selector.appendChild(option);
});
```

```html
<select id="selector"></select>
```

You could also do this instead:

```js
var currencies = [{
  id: 0,
  name: "euro"
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: "usd"
}];
var selector = document.querySelector("#selector");


selector.innerHTML = currencies.map(currency => `<option value=${currency.id}>${currency.name}</option>`).join("");
```

```html
<select id="selector"></select>
```

If you want to convert the whole `forEach` into an arrow function you can do:

```js
var currencies = [{
  id: 0,
  name: "euro"
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: "usd"
}];
var selector = document.querySelector("#selector");


var populateCurrencies = () => {
  currencies.forEach(currency => {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = currency.id;
    option.innerHTML = currency.name;
    selector.appendChild(option);
  });
};

populateCurrencies();
```

```html
<select id="selector"></select>
```

Though, you could just use normal functions instead.